# Cut corners in image PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5, intervention

Im working with Intervention Image to make a frame. Now im stuck on a part to cut off the edges. I need 4 of those images to make them fit as a frame. I know i can use the Intervention Image library to rotate the image, but i have no clue to cut those corners. Anyone has a idea how to achieve this?

Original:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create two polygons and fill them with transparent colors.

http://image.intervention.io/api/polygon

An example:

```
$img = Image::make('foo/bar/baz.jpg')->encode('png');
$w = $img->width();
$h = $img->height();
$points = [0,0,$width,0,$width,$width,0,0];
$img->polygon($points, function($d) {
    $d->background("transparent");
});
$points = [0,$height,$width,$height,$width,$height-$width,0,$height];
$img->polygon($points, function($d) {
    $d->background("transparent");
});
$img->save('foo/bar/baz_cut.png'); // jpg won't have transparency
```

Comment: I used the background('transparent') but then i received a error: Unable to read color (transparent). Any idea what it can be?

Comment: Then you can use `rgba(0,0,0,0)` for getting that transparency.

Comment: Yeah i've seen that mate, thanks! Did that trick. You're my savior!

Comment: Do you maybe now if there is another function like $image->insert('to/path/file.png') to insert an instance?

Comment: You can use $img->getCore() and use GD methods like imagecopyresampled() to do what you want.